# Failure to use accelerometer with HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, android-emulator

I wonder why things go wrong is the application that I'm doing?
He did not start playing when I shake the phone.
I followed the instructions on this site, http://software.intel.com/pt-br/articles/create-handbell-using-html5-and-phonegap, but I do not quite understand how it works.
Here is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>BellShapes</title>

      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

       function onLoad(){
        // Aguardar o carregamento do Cordova
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        // inicialização
        bellrightring = document.getElementById("bellrightring");
        bellleftring = document.getElementById("bellleftring");
        bellleft = document.getElementById("bellleft");
        bellright = document.getElementById("bellright");
        bellcenter = document.getElementById("bellcenter");
        // inicialização da mídia
        bellsound = new Media("/android_asset/www/resources/bell.mp3",
        onRingSuccess(bellsound), onRingError);
        bellend = new Media("/android_asset/www/resources/bell-end.mp3",
        onRingSuccess(bellend), onRingError);
        }
        function sign(val, delta) {
            if (typeof delta == undefined) delta=0
            if (val > 0 && Math.abs(val)-delta > 0) return 1;
            else if (val<0 && Math.abs(val)-delta > 0) return -1;
            else return 0;
        }
        function isShaking(last, current, threshold) {
        var deltaX = Math.abs(last.x - current.x),
            deltaY = Math.abs(last.y - current.y),
            deltaZ = Math.abs(last.z - current.z);
                return ((deltaX > threshold && deltaY > threshold) ||
                    (deltaX > threshold && deltaZ > threshold) ||
                    (deltaY > threshold && deltaZ > threshold) || deltaX > threshold);   
        }
        accelID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, options);
        function onSuccess(acceleration) {
            var x = acceleration.x;
            var y = acceleration.y;
            var z = acceleration.z;
            var t = false;
            if (previous){
            if (isShaking(previous, acceleration, 10)){     
            moveBell(sign(x)); 
            bellsound.play();
            accelerated = true;
            }
            else {
                stopBell(acceleration);
                if (accelerated == true){
                bellend.play();
            }
            accelerated = false;
        }
    }

        previous = acceleration;
    }



</script>  

  </head>
  <body id="onLoad">
    <div id="handbell">

        <div id="bellcenter" class="position"></div>

        <div id="bellright" class="position"></div>

        <div id="bellleft" class="position"></div>

        <div id="bellrightring" class="ring"></div>

        <div id="bellleftring" class="ring"></div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I do not know much about javascript, so I would appreciate if you could explain in a simpler way.

Comment: type of is actually "typeof". maybe more wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

In your body tag you have written

```
<body id="onLoad">
```

This should be

```
<body onLoad="onLoad()">
```

You need to have the function onLoad called when the page loads.

Alternatively, you could remove the id and forget about the onload in the body tag.
Then add this one line to the Javascript.

```
window.addEventListener("load", onLoad);
```